# How to run a single role tasks(multiple tasks) on multiple hosts..?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a main.YAML file inside a single role/test/tasks. i.e /roles/test/tasks/main.yaml. In my main.yaml I have defined multiple tasks and want to run those multiple tasks on multiple hosts. say - first two tasks should run on hostA, next two should run on hostB and so on...How can i do this..?

I have tried giving tags to multiple tasks inside the role and then calling those in the main playbook:

```
- hosts: A
  tags:
    - master
  role:
    test

- hosts: B
  tags:
    - slave
  role: 
    test
```

But tasks defined in a role are being run on all the hosts instead of the specified hosts.

I'm running: `ansible-playbook -i hosts mail.yaml`

Please help!!!!

Comment: Update the question with `hosts`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"First two tasks should run on host A, next two should run on host B and so on.."*

A: Let's have a couple of tasks in main.yml

```
$ cat roles/test/tasks/main.yaml
- debug:
    msg: Task1
  tags: t1
- debug:
    msg: Task2
  tags: t2
- debug:
    msg: Task3
  tags: t3
- debug:
    msg: Task4
  tags: t4
```

This playbook should run "First two tasks on host A"

```
$ cat playbookA.yml
- hosts: A
  roles:
    - test

$ ansible-playbook playbookA.yml -t t1,t2
```

This playbook should run "Next two tasks on host B"

```
$ cat playbookB.yml
- hosts: B
  roles:
    - test

$ ansible-playbook playbookB.yml -t t3,t4
```

---

> Q: *"I don't want to use tag flag while running the playbook. Is there any other approach?"*

A: No. There is no other approach with 'ansible-playbook'.

- See [Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags) and [Tag Inheritance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance) in particular.
- Quoting from 'man ansible-playbook'

> ```
>    -t, --tags
>       only run plays and tasks tagged with these values
> ```

- It's possible to set environment variable *ANSIBLE_RUN_TAGS* or configure ini key *run* in the *tags* ini section. See [TAGS_RUN](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#tags-run). For example, the commands below will give the same results

```
    $ ansible-playbook playbookB.yml -t t3,t4
    $ export ANSIBLE_RUN_TAGS='t3,t4'
    $ ansible-playbook playbookB.yml
```

- See [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's possible to put command line arguments into the file [env/cmdline](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#env-cmdline). For example

> --tags one,two --skip-tags three -u ansible --become

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir but I don't want to use tag flag while the running the playbook. Is there any other approach where i can define in mail playbook and simply run it. Moreover, why my playbook did not run like I showed in the question..?

Comment: It's not possible. I've updated the answer. You didn't show in the question how you run your playbook.

Comment: i'm running: ansible-playbook -i hosts mail.yaml